# Why am I receiving different results with nearly the same Python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a sanity check. The `top1` and `top2` functions are nearly the same but output very different contents for the `freq` variable. Why? What am I not seeing?

```
def top1(nums, k):
    count = {}
    
    for i in nums:
        if i not in count:
            count[i] = 1
        else:
            count[i] += 1
    
    freq = (len(nums) + 1) * [[]]

    print('count', count)
    print('freq', freq)
    for n, c in count.items():
        freq[c].append(n)
    print('freq', freq)


def top2(nums, k):
    count = {}

    for n in nums:
        count[n] = 1 + count.get(n, 0)

    freq = [[] for i in range(len(nums) + 1)]

    print('count', count)
    print('freq', freq)
    for n, c in count.items():
        freq[c].append(n)
    print('freq', freq)

top1([1], 1)
print()
top2([1], 1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
count {1: 1}
freq [[], []]
freq [[1], [1]]

count {1: 1}
freq [[], []]
freq [[], [1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
freq = (len(nums) + 1) * [[]]
```

multiplies a list to create a list of multiple references to the same list.  Mutating one entry in the outer list affects all of the other entries, because each entry is a reference to a single shared list object.

```
freq = [[] for i in range(len(nums) + 1)]
```

is a list comprehension that creates a list of multiple distinct lists.  Mutating one entry in the outer list does not affect the other inner lists.

Comment: This is it. Thank you! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can cause StackOverflow says I have to wait 11 minutes to do so.